# Rails app takes a long time to generate error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

My Rails app generates error page very slowly (Rail 3.1/3.2, ruby 1.9.2/1.9.3). E.g. I have added my_bad_variable to some .haml template and

`Rendered fees/index.html.haml within layouts/application (97752.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99579ms`

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `my_bad_variable' for #<#:0x00000003bbf0c8>):

After deleting this fake variable:

`Completed 200 OK in 327ms (Views: 274.7ms | ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue when I upgraded to rails 3.2. I added this initializer to fix it:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      alias :inspect :to_s
    end
  end
end
```

I think it was related to ree. Are you using ree?

Comment: He's using Ruby 1.9, so he's not using REE. However, this did fix the problem for me and I *am* using REE.

Comment: Same issue for me at Rails 3.2.0. This also fixed it for me – why does this work? And thanks for writing this answer :)

Comment: more info http://devblog.agworld.com.au/post/24392662859/rubys-inspect-considered-harmful

Comment: @stereoscott You have to login to Tumblr to see the article... 

Comment: Can anybody explain the reasoning why this would resolve the issue?